# Javascript Program Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I have a syntax error that I don't know how to fix. This is the code:

```
function computer(speed, hdspace, ram)
{
    this.speed=speed;
    this.hdspace=hdspace;
    this.ram=ram;
    this.price=get_price();
}
function get_price()
{
    var the_price=500;
    the_price += (this.speed == "2GHz") ? 200 : 100;
    the_price += (this.hdspace == "80GB") ? 50 : 25;
    the_price += (this.ram == "1GB") ? 150 : 75;
    return the_price;
}

var work_computer = new computer("2GHz", "80GB", "1GB");
var home_computer = new computer("1.5GHz", "40GB", "512MB");
var laptop_computer = new computer("1GHz", "20GB", "256");

var price = get_price();
var work_computer_price = work_computer.price();
var home_computer_price = home_computer.price();
var laptop_computer_price = laptop_computer.price();

document.write("<h1>Prices of the computers you requested:</h1>");
document.write("<h3><br/>Work Computer: </h3>"+work_computer);
document.write("Price: $"+work_computer_price);
document.write("<br/>");
document.write("Home Computer: "+home_computer);
document.write("Price: $"+home_computer_price);
document.write("<br/>");
document.write("Laptop Computer: "+laptop_computer);
document.write("Price: $"+laptop_computer_price);
```

On line 22, there is an error saying: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'price' of object # is not a function
This is line 22:

```
var work_computer_price = work_computer.price();
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Certainly not a SyntaxError, but a TypeError. **Hint**: Functions are invoked using `()`, and passed by reference when `()` is removed. **/End of hint**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take away the parentheses when you assign `this.price`:

```
this.price=get_price;
```

You want to set the "price" property to reference the function itself, not the return value of calling it.

Answer (score 1):

you better declare `getPrice()` as a member of the `computer`'s `prototype`, like this:

```
var computer = function(speed, hdspace, ram)
{
    this.speed=speed;
    this.hdspace=hdspace;
    this.ram=ram;
    this.price=get_price();
}
computer.prototype = {
    get_price: function()
    {
        var the_price=500;
        the_price += (this.speed == "2GHz") ? 200 : 100;
        the_price += (this.hdspace == "80GB") ? 50 : 25;
        the_price += (this.ram == "1GB") ? 150 : 75;
        return the_price;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work if it weren't for the syntax error :-)  (The function needs to be declared `get_price: function() { ... }` )

Comment: thanks, i was in a rush and it slipt, just noticed and corrected.

Comment: If overwriting `.prototype`, make sure to restore `.constructor`.

Answer (score 0):

how are you?

The problem is that price is not a function, its an attribute.

So basically:

```
var work_computer_price = work_computer.price;
```

will work.

Cheers!